# Default music player in system tray icon?

Tags: release-hera, settings, desktop, default

Folks;
using current elementary, I stumbled across some rather weird behaviour related to the default music player. As "Music" doesn't work for some of my use cases, I tried other players (such as byte from the App Store or lollypop from flatpak).

Generally, this seems to work. However, in the system tray in the "Volume" menu, I will keep seeing "Music" icon and navigation buttons on top of the menu *most of the time*. I remember having seen lollypop in there once after starting the laptop in the morning but I have no idea how to make lollypop / whatever-default-music-player permanently appear in there... Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kristian

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you follow my advice and pick another application than Music. Lollypop is a good example.

Usually it's very easy to choose another music player.

```
Open System Settings
Click at Applications
Change default Music Player
```

Anyway the app volume settings shows in tray when you click the volume icon, when you run the music app (Spotify, Lollypop, Audacity etc.). If you will run the Spotify it will be there, the same for Lollypop. It disappears, when you turn off the music app. Hope my explanation is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve. :) But I'm not able to get "Music" permanently out of that menu, even if it's not installed anymore. This is a bit weird...

Comment: Strange. Then something is wrong. The problem is that I am unable to investigate it further. I do not know is it logged to some log file in /var/log/messages . Worth check it: sudo cat /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

Search in AppCenter the Music App and remove it.[image: Music app]

Comment: That's exactly what I did already. Lollypop is my default player. Meanwhile, however, I *think* I have found a pattern here. After rebooting the device, I see "Lollypop" as music player in the system tray volume icon (and navigation icons work). Good. As soon as I play, say, music in a browser window for a while - and stop that, "Music" shows up again and navigation icons are broken again.